# Doxygen: errors during compilation of OpenFOAM 1.7.1 documentation

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to generate the OpenFOAM 1.7.1 source documentation using doxygen 1.6.3 and the Doxyfile that came with the OpenFOAM source. Unfortunately, some things obviously went wrong during compilation:

- the `All`, `Classes`, `Namespaces` etc links that should be displayed on the main page are not working. Nothing happens when I click them.
- When I navigate to a class using the tabs, both the inheritance diagram and the collaboration diagram only show the class itself, nothing else - even in cases where I know that these diagrams are quite big.
- The search does not work. When I type something in the search box and press Enter, nothing happens.

I looked at the output of the doxygen run and while it threw a lot of warnings, I got no error messages. It complained about:

- no matching file members for classes, operators and functions, no matching class members, no uniquely matching class members,
- documented but undeclared or undefined functions,
- Unsupported xml/html tag `<cloudname>`,
- many blocks of:
  `</li>` tag without matching `<li>`
  `</ul>` tag without matching `<ul>`
  unexpected end of comment while inside `<ul>` block

Could these possibly have ruined the search? I can not edit all files to get rid of the warnings, there are just too many of them.

I have modified the Doxyfile that came with OpenFOAM by setting the output file extension to `html` (was `php` before) and adding the line `SERVER_BASED_SEARCH = NO`, but that didn't change anything. I did that because the Doxyfile template the OpenFOAM developers used is for doxygen 1.5.3 (that's what it says in the first line) and as far as I know the additional search option came with 1.6.2.

What could have gone wrong here? The OpenFOAM developers seem to have been successful in generating the docs earlier, they are just not online any more.

If anyone has a link to compiled online docs for OF-1.7.1, I'll happily use those - I just didn't find anything but the most recent version.

---

I found a guide to using the doxygen-related files (config, header, ...) of OF-2.0.0 for creating the documentation of OF-1.7.1, using doxygen 1.7.5.1 here: http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/78529-building-openfoam1-7-0-source-2.html

I used doxygen 1.7.6.1 instead (downloaded the wrong version and just tried it with that), and in the doxyfile:
`INPUT_FILTER = doxyFilt`
`FILTER_SOURCE_FILES = YES`
`SHORT_NAMES = NO`

I now have all tabs and the Javascript search working, and all diagrams seems to be complete.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not overly familiar with OpenFOAM, but you may want to try:

- Use Doxygen 1.5.3 instead of Doxygen 1.6.3. Since 1.5.3 is referenced in their files, it will likely be more compatible with their source (and utility scripts).
- Verify that `doxyFilt` is in your path: `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin`. This script is invoked by doxygen and will preprocess the source files before they are consumed by Doxygen.

With the above I was able to verify that the `Classes`, `Namespace` and associated tabs were working correctly.

You may also need to take a look at the utility scripts located at `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/doc/Doxygen/tools` as they appear to be related with identifying problems in and fixing up the generated documentation.

Comment: I've downloaded doxygen 1.5.3 and used it to build the documentation, but no luck. `doxyFilt` is in the path. As you said, the tabs are ok - but the search is still broken and the inheritance and collaboration diagrams still only show the class they were created for.

Comment: I just found out that the Javascript based search was introduced with doxygen 1.6.0, so I cannot have a locally running search when I generate documentation with doxygen 1.5.3.

Comment: In the past I've had problems with Doxygen because its scanner/parser is not quite up to the job. Consequently different versinos have behaved differently on the same source code, sometimes even complaining when there is no apparwent problem. So switching Doxygen versions is probably the way to go.